# Add a new column to a data-frame where values are dependent on previous row values of the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (df) were the head looks like:

```
  BB   NEW_DATE     PICKED
1123 03/10/2018 03/10/2018
1123 04/10/2018 04/10/2018
1123 05/10/2018 05/10/2018
1123 09/10/2018 09/10/2018
1123 04/01/2013 01/04/2013
1123 07/01/2013 07/01/2013
1123 08/01/2013 08/01/2013
```

I am trying to add a new column called `FINAL` who's values are dependent in part on previous row values of `FINAL`.

```
if df['PICKED'] < df['FINAL'].shift(-1):
    if df['NEW_DATE'].isnumeric():
        df['FINAL'] = df['NEW_DATE'] 
    else:
        df['FINAL'] = df['PICKED']
    df['FINAL'] = df['PICKED']
```

For each row if `PICKED` less than the previous rows value of `FINAL`, then if `NEW_DATE` is a valid date the current row value of `FINAL` is equal to the current row value of NEW_DATE otherwise FINAL is equal to `PICKED`.  If `PICKED` is greater or equal to the previous rows value of `FINAL` then `FINAL` is equal to `PICKED`.

so in the above data-frame the `FINAL` column would look like;

```
  BB     NEW_DATE       PICKED       FINAL
1123   03/10/2018   03/10/2018  03/10/2018
1123   04/10/2018   04/10/2018  04/10/2018
1123   05/10/2018   05/10/2018  05/10/2018
1123   09/10/2018   09/10/2018  09/10/2018
1123   04/01/2013   01/04/2013  04/01/2013
1123   07/01/2013   07/01/2013  07/01/2013
1123   08/01/2013   08/01/2013  08/01/2013
```

I have tried without any sucess to code this using:

```
df['FINAL'] = np.where(df['PICKED'] < df['FINAL'].shift(-1), df.NEW_DATE.fillna(df.DATE), df['PICKED'])
```

I've also tried:

```
for row in df.iterrows:

    if index == 0 :
        row['FINAL'] = row['NEW_DATE']
    else:

        if row['PICKED'] < row['FINAL'].shift(-1):
            if isinstance(row['NEW_DATE'], pd.DatetimeIndex):
                row['FINAL'] = row['NEW_DATE']
            else:
                row['FINAL'] = row['PICKED']
        else:
            row['FINAL'] = row['PICKED']
```

but I get the error :  `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`

Comment: You may need for loop here

Comment: Do you always have `df['NEW_DATE'] <= df['PICKED']` or not especially?

Comment: Hi Ben, no df['NEW_DATE'] can be an invalid date format for some rows

Comment: @Stacey And for the case where it is a valid date format?

Comment: df['NEW_DATE'] can be greater than df['PICKED']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not think a way without loop for, so here is one way.

```
# Initalise the first value of FINAL that will be the previous value 
# in the first iteration of the loop
prev_final = df.loc[0,'PICKED'] 

#create a list containing the data to create the column FINAL after
list_final = [prev_final] 

# loop over the rows with itertuples, not the first row as it has been take care of before
for new_date, picked in df.loc[1:,['NEW_DATE','PICKED']].itertuples(index=False):

    # check the two conditions at once as if both are not met, then the value in FINAL is from PICKED
    if (picked < prev_final) & isinstance(new_date, pd.datetime):
        # add the value from NEW_DATE
        list_final.append(new_date) 
        # and update the prev_final for the next iteration of the loop
        prev_final = new_date 

    else: # same idea if conditions not met
        list_final.append(picked)
        prev_final = picked

#outside of the loop, create the column with the list
df['FINAL'] = list_final

print(df)
     BB   NEW_DATE     PICKED      FINAL
0  1123 2018-03-10 2018-03-10 2018-03-10
1  1123 2018-04-10 2018-04-10 2018-04-10
2  1123 2018-05-10 2018-05-10 2018-05-10
3  1123 2018-09-10 2018-09-10 2018-09-10
4  1123 2013-04-01 2013-01-04 2013-04-01
5  1123 2013-07-01 2013-07-01 2013-07-01
6  1123 2013-08-01 2013-08-01 2013-08-01
```

Comment: Thank-you so much you really went the extra mile. I now know how to iterate over a data-frame column